# Overlay on image equal to fixed size of image

Tags: css, image, hover

I need hover effect on an image, fixed to image size even when image become large or small in responsive.

```
<div>
<img scr="abc.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: What sort of hover effect? Could do with just CSS if the effect can be done with a filter, or JS if not.

Comment: If you want to make hover with overlay effect, you should set the width&height of image.

Comment: So put an inline container element around the image then ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.img-wrap{
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.img-wrap > img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: none;
}
.img-wrap:hover > .overlay{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrap">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <img src="http://www.addictedtoibiza.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/example.png">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. an easy solution

Comment: @ShakilAhmad It's my pleasure